# Guardar un Valor Formateado ("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") en dato de una tabla DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

tengo un problema al cambiar el valor de una tabla llenada de una BD dicha valor "va_fecha" es de formato Datetime, en la base de dato el valor es ***va_fecha="12-04-2019"*** 
pero cuando recupero el valor y lo gardo en un datatable el formato se cambia y queda asi ***va_fecha="12/04/2019 0:00:00"***
ya intente convertirlo pero no tube resultados positivos
mi codigo:

```
//lenar datos
tab_pub001 = o_pub001._05(cod_usuario);

foreach (DataRow row in tab_pub001.Rows)
{
    DateTime fe_cha;

    var Invoice_date = Convert.ToDateTime(tab_pub001.Rows[va_ind_ice]["va_fecha"]).ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");
    fe_cha = Convert.ToDateTime(Invoice_date);
    tab_pub001.Rows[va_ind_ice]["va_fecha"] = fe_cha;

    va_ind_ice = va_ind_ice + 1;
}

rpt_mis_pub.DataSource = tab_pub001;
rpt_mis_pub.DataBind();
```

también intente de la siguiente manera pero no me funciono aqui el string si cambia al formato que quiero pero en mi datatable sigue mostrandome el formato: **va_facha="12/04/2019 0:00:00"**

```
//lenar datos
tab_pub001 = o_pub001._05(cod_usuario);

foreach (DataRow row in tab_pub001.Rows)
{
    string fe_cha;

     fe_cha = Convert.ToDateTime(tab_pub001.Rows[va_ind_ice]["va_fecha"]).ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");
    tab_pub001.Rows[va_ind_ice]["va_fecha"] = fe_cha;

    va_ind_ice = va_ind_ice + 1;
}

rpt_mis_pub.DataSource = tab_pub001;
rpt_mis_pub.DataBind();
```

Comment: que es `rpt_mis_pub` ? es un reporte, porque deberias asignar el campo Datetime sin formato y aplicarlo dentro del reporte, no necesitas convertir nada previamente

Comment: Como se vea en el DataTable no importa, porque representa un DateTime, el formato que apliques en el campo donde visualices el valor es lo que debes definir correctamente

Comment: @leandrotuttini rpt_mis_pub Es un Repeater

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te dijeron en los comentarios no importa como guardes una fecha (tipo datetime), al momento de leerla y mostrarla puedes formatear como tu quieras.

Si te molesta que tenga la hora puedes usar tipo Date en vez de DateTime, te dejo un ejemplo.

```
 foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            var fecha = DateTime.Parse(item["date_test1"].ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Console.Write("Fecha: "+fecha);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.